# Parallel Median Filter

Tags: java, parallel-processing

So I've been working on a median filter* (comparing sequential to parallel, since I'm learning how to code concurrently), but the parallel version runs indefinitely for a large input (about 100k; it runs fine for less).

In essence, the code takes in a file, filters it given a certain window size, then writes it to a new file. New to parallel programming, so I'm kind of lost when it comes to what might be wrong here.

```
//import everything

public class SecondMedianFilter extends RecursiveAction {
    float[] numbers;
    static int filter;
    int window;
    int length;
    int lo;
    int hi;

    static final int SEQUENTIAL_CUTOFF = 500;


    float[] outArray;

    public SecondMedianFilter(float[] numbers, int filter, int lo, int hi) {
        this.numbers = numbers;
        this.filter = filter;
        this.lo = lo;
        this.hi = hi;
        length = numbers.length;
        window = (filter - 1) / 2;
    }

    public float[] getRes() {
        return result;
    }


    protected void compute() {

        result = new float[length];

        if ((hi - lo) < SEQUENTIAL_CUTOFF) {

            for (int a = lo; a < hi; a++) {


                for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                    if (i < window || i >= length - window) {
                        result[i] = numbers[i];
                    } else {
                        float[] subArray = Arrays.copyOfRange(numbers, i - window, i + window + 1);
                        Arrays.sort(subArray);
                        float median = subArray[(subArray.length / 2)];
                        result[i] = median;

                    }
                }

            }
        } else {

            SecondMedianFilter left = new SecondMedianFilter(filtered, filter, lo, (hi + lo) / 2);
            SecondMedianFilter right = new SecondMedianFilter(filtered, filter, (hi + lo) / 2, hi);
            left.fork();
            right.compute();
            left.join();
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //reads in a file, processes each line into an array of floats that
        // I call inArray, which gets filtered into outIntArray


        float[] outIntArray = new float[inArray.length];

        if (window < 3 || window > 21 || window % 2 == 0) {
            System.out.println("Window size error.");
        } else {

            SecondMedianFilter smf = new SecondMedianFilter(inArray, window, 0, inArray.length);
            smf.compute();
            outIntArray = smf.getRes();


            // loops through outIntArray and writes to file.
        }//end main           
    }
}
```

Doing it sequentially appears to work (under a second for about 1 000 000 elements), and yet my concurrent version takes almost 4 just to do 10 000 elements. As I said, brand new to parallel programming, so I'm quite lost. Is there an approach to doing a median filter in parallel that I'm missing?

(* Median filter = take a certain window of the array, sort them and replace the original element at that index with the median of the sorted sub-array; for example: 2, 80, 6, 3, 1 results in 2, 6, 6, 3, 1.)

*For example:

```
Taking in this file: 
5.0
13.2
-2.6
22.3
12.4
-0.21
23.1
-0.2454
```

It'll read that into an array [5.0, 13.2, -2.6, 22.3, 12.4, -0.21, 23.1, -0.2454]
    With a window size of, say, 3.  In order to be applicable for filtering, an element must have n elements before it and n elements after it, where n = (window - 1)/2; hence, an element, in the case of window = 3, must have 1 element on either side of it.  If it doesn't satisfy that condition, that element is taken as-is.

So 5.0 will remain, given that it doesn't have an element before it. But 13.2 satisfies the condition - hence, a sub-array is taken [5.0, 13.2, -2.6]. This array is then sorted (using .sort(): [-2.6, 5.0, 13.2]), then the median is taken to be 5.0. 13.2 is subsequently replaced with 5.0 in the final array, which now looks like [5.0, 5.0,...].

Next it moves on to -2.6 - it has an element before and one after, so the sub-array [-2.6, 22.3, 12.4] is taken, sorted, and the median of 12.4 is added to the final array: [5.0, 5.0, 12.4,...]. It repeats this process until all elements in the original array have been visited. It then writes the final array to a file, but this isn't particularly relevant (unless this can be done in parallel somehow - which I doubt, but as I said: complete noob here).

Comment: A [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would make people more willing to help :)

Answer (score 0):

You're processing is totally parallizable. Indeed you can compute the *median filter* for every single subset of elements (because you don't change the content of the original array in your calculations). So, yes, you can do it in parallel.

Said this, even if I don't know all the details of the **RecursiveAction**, I would say that you miss the whole *threads* part. I've checked a bit and any recursive action should be invoked by an **ForkJoinPool** class. This one then handles the threads and fork/join them.

Furthmore, splitting the operations on right and left (with two different calls) requires that you **fork** and **join** both them later.

I expect something like this to have a working configuration:

```
public class SecondMedianFilter extends RecursiveAction {
... 

protected void compute() {

    result = new float[length];

    if ((hi - lo) < SEQUENTIAL_CUTOFF) {

        for (int a = lo; a < hi; a++) {


            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                if (i < window || i >= length - window) {
                    result[i] = numbers[i];
                } else {
                    float[] subArray = Arrays.copyOfRange(numbers, i - window, i + window + 1);
                    Arrays.sort(subArray);
                    float median = subArray[(subArray.length / 2)];
                    result[i] = median;

                }
            }

        }
    } else {

        SecondMedianFilter left = new SecondMedianFilter(filtered, filter, lo, (hi + lo) / 2);
        SecondMedianFilter right = new SecondMedianFilter(filtered, filter, (hi + lo) / 2, hi);
        left.fork();
        //CODE CHANGES FROM HERE
        right.fork();
        //right.compute(); <- IS IMPLICIT IN THE FORK 
        left.join();
        right.join();
        //TO HERE
    }
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    //reads in a file, processes each line into an array of floats that
    // I call inArray, which gets filtered into outIntArray


    float[] outIntArray = new float[inArray.length];

    if (window < 3 || window > 21 || window % 2 == 0) {
        System.out.println("Window size error.");
    } else {
        // CODE CHANGES FROM HERE
        ForkJoinPool pool = new ForkJoinPool(); // WHO HANDLES THE THREADS 
        SecondMedianFilter smf = new SecondMedianFilter(inArray, window, 0, inArray.length);
        //smf.compute(); <- DUTY OF THREAD POOL
        pool.invoke(smf); //  START OF PROCESSING 
        outIntArray = smf.getRes();


        // loops through outIntArray and writes to file.
    }//end main           
}
```

}

I'll provide you two links, they'll explain enough in detail how the whole process works (where one shows both the parallel and sequential approachs).

http://www.concretepage.com/java/jdk7/example-of-recursiveaction-in-java

http://www.logicbig.com/how-to/java/fork-and-join-recursive-action/

EDIT
I've not checked how you're algorithm works (I expect that it splits the array in two up to when it comes to to a bound case), so I've just added pieces of code according to what you've written.